Halide scheduling issue for Func used in 2 places
I'm a beginner in Halide and got an error in a ~1000 line Halide program.
I've reduced it to minimal size:
#include "Halide.h"

namespace {

using namespace Halide;

Var x("x"), y("y"), c("c"), yo("yo"), yi("yi");

class Cord : public Halide::Generator<Cord> {
public:
    Input<Buffer<int32_t, 3>> G{ "G" };
    Output<Buffer<int32_t, 3>> output{"output"};

    Cord():Q("Q"), M("M") {}

    void generate() {

        // Algorithm
        Func G2("G2");

        G2(x, y, c) = G(x, y, c)*G(x, y, c);
        
        M(x, y, c) = 2*G2(x, y, c);
        Q(x, y, c) = 3*G2(x, y, c);// + M(x, y, c);
        
        output(x, y, c) = Q(x, y, c) + M(x, y, c);

        // Schedule 
        if (!using_autoscheduler()) {  
            int strip_size = 480; 

            G2.store_root().compute_at(Q, yi);
            //G2.compute_root();

            Q.compute_root()
                .split(y, yo, yi, strip_size / 2);
        }
    }

private:
    Func Q, M;
};

}  // namespace

HALIDE_REGISTER_GENERATOR(Cord, cord)


Gives build error : Func "G2$0" is computed at the following invalid location...
If I replace The G2 schedule with the commented one: G2.compute_root(), it works fine. I'd like to use the original schedule as its faster in the original computation from which this code is derived.
Why does the original schedule not work? I'm guessing it has something to do with G2 being needed to compute Q as well as to compute M which is used to compute output. Removing the M term from output makes it work.
The actual program, which this is a reduction of, has, instead of output(x, y, c) = Q(x, y, c) + M(x, y, c); a long series of computations on Q and separately on M and the results of each are then combined in a way that requires equal size domains for each. These long computations have multiple compute_root() in them. That's why I did a Q.compute_root() instead of making it evaluate in output's loop.
Thanks

The original schedule doesn't work because in Halide the compute at location of a producer has to enclose all of its consumers. I think you want having the store at location enclose the consumer to be enough, but unfortunately Halide doesn't support that (because we'd have to infer bounds for the loop over Q to cover all the uses of Q but also to make sure the values of G2 that get computed as a side effect are then enough to satisfy all the uses of G2 in M).
You're going to have to either compute_root G2, or compute it twice. If G2 is small and only used in one place in the loop nests for Q and M, you can just inline it. Otherwise, you can use clone_in to make a separate copy of G2 for use in each place:
G2.clone_in(M).compute_at(M, yi);
G2.compute_at(Q, yi);


Thanks a lot Andrew. It's great to get authoritative answers from  one of Halide's authors himself.

I might be able to get away with computing G2 twice here. For future reference, if the computation is expensive, is there some way of trading off accuracy for not having to recompute it? I was thinking of something along the lines of how BoundaryConditions::repeat_edge() is used on Buffers. Would I have to do the first computation of G2 for Q and store the result in a Buffer and then use it with BoundaryConditions::repeat_edge() as input for computing M?

A somewhat related question: what if I want to output an intermediate result (say Q) for debugging.  I could make Q an output Buffer. That would allow me to output it and see it. However, I wouldn't then be able to continue the computation past this point as the next stage that takes Q as input may need it evaluated on a different domain than the Q Buffer size. Is my understanding correct? Is there any way to output intermediate values conveniently in Halide?
